# JSF View Scope does not shutdown

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

First:

I have two Managed Beans.

Bean A:

- @ViewScope
- Contains a lazyloading datatable depending on some session value, initialized in the @PostConstruct

Bean B:

- @ViewScope
- Changing the session value which is used in Bean A

I do following;

- setting my session data with the JSF site using Bean B
- loading the jsf site which uses Bean A
- setting other session data with Bean B
- loading the jsf which uses Bean A again

The Problem is following:

If I am loading the JSF site with Bean A again, the PostConstruct which is initializing the datatable is not loaded again.

I thought that if I use the view scope, the ManagedBean would be destroyed if I navigate through different JSF sites.

Please help me to understand this Problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly are you performing the step *"loading the jsf which uses Bean A again"*. By a new HTTP GET request, right?

Comment: And that request is for sure not served from the browser cache? Okay, how are you managing your beans? Using JSF's own `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` or something else?

Comment: Every bean is annotated with javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean and there own view annotation javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped for this case. For the most beans I use javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped but in this case I need to reload the constructor or the post construct because I have a depend on an other object the user can select in other jsf sites.

Comment: The JSF Site which is using Bean A has a Dialog, which uses an other managed Bean C, also with ViewScoped. Is that a maybe a Problem?

Comment: Normaly I use a jetty. Deploying my application in tomcat does following: I started some get requests on the SAME jsf site using Bean A and C and every time both managed beans with ViewScoped linked, get created new..

Comment: There is something other, too... All managed beans are extending from a parent managed bean which has also the managed bean annotation using session scope to provide some functions in all extending managed beans..

Comment: If I use jetty, ViewScoped sites behave like SessionScoped Beans and if I use tomcat, ViewScoped and SessionScoped sites behave like Request. Now I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

It should yes. The view scope should stay in-tact for as long as you stay on the same view.

There have been many problems with this scope in past versions of JSF however, including relating to PostConstruct; which version are you using right now? It should mention that in the logs during application startup.